# migration error in Digitalocen site deploy

Tags: laravel, migration, digital-ocean

when I run php artisan migrate , there is showing error like this

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /root/sewa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")
      /root/sewa/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")
      /root/sewa/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

can you help me to solve this

Comment: Do you have the proper database settings in your .env file???

Comment: You should check your database credentials and also database permission . again I want  to share that using root as username for database is not recommended

Comment: yes, what mean permisson? password